# Copying the latest data from an accumulating list to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to reflect the the latest updated data from another sheet. One possible solution to that is getting a reference cell from the source sheet. For example:

[image: list example 1]

I could have created a cell below and I want that the cell that contains the Latest Balance (like the `P1700.34` above) to be seen on the other sheet where I will put it. So that, let's say, when I deduct `P700.34` and the last new cell would be `P1000.00` then on the other sheet, it would reflect that `P1000.00` as the latest remaining balance:

[image: list example 2]

Is it possible and/or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

> My problem now is: I want to find a way to not manually update the V18's formula(=V10) anymore. Ex. if I add one transaction, V18 will then be =V11

Based on the comment,

**V18**:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/(V4:V17<>""),V4:V17))
```

Or

```
 =INDIRECT("R[-"&COUNTBLANK(V4:V17)+1&"]C",0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is another worksheet or just another tab in the same worksheet.

If it's another tab,

Sheet2A1:

```
 =Sheet1!V18
```

If it's another new worksheet,

```
 =IMPORTRANGE ("SPREADSHEETKEY", "Sheet1!V18")
```

SYNTAX: [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

If this does not solve your problem, please explain more.

Comment: Sorry, if it's confusing. 
So, what I have already done before asking this question: 
1.To get the new Remaining Balance in V10, I use this formula =V9-T10
2.Simply copy the last Remaining Balance to V18 by using =V10
3.On the other tab/sheet below, I use this =if (isblank($V18),Bank!$V18, "").
 
Where "Bank" is the name of the sheet/tab that has the Bank Transactions.

My problem now is: 
I want to find a way to not manually update the V18's formula(=V10)  anymore. Ex. if I add one transaction, V18 will then be =V11

Comment: I tried the simple formula " =Bank!V18" in the other sheet/tab, but doesn't work.

Comment: @Meg Do you have spaces in sheet names? Also, Check my other answer.